# Spring Security 4. Exception when specifying access decision manager

Tags: java, spring-security

I am using Spring Security 4 in my Java project. When I specify tag access-decision-manager-ref in http element I have this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0' while setting constructor argument with key [13]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported configuration attributes: [hasRole('ADMIN')]

Here is my xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
     use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/*"
        access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <security:remember-me key="terror-key" />
    <security:logout delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
        success-handler-ref="logoutRedirectToAny" />
    <security:form-login login-page="/custom_login"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="serverErrorHandler" />
</security:http>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager>
    <security:authentication-provider
        user-service-ref="inMemoryUserServiceWithCustomUser" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="inMemoryUserServiceWithCustomUser"
    class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.spring.CustomInMemoryUserDetailsManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.model.User">
                <constructor-arg value="admin" />
                <constructor-arg value="admin" />
                <constructor-arg>
                    <list>
                        <bean
                            class="org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority">
                            <constructor-arg value="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </constructor-arg>
                <constructor-arg value="Scarioni" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="logoutRedirectToAny"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler">
    <property name="targetUrlParameter" value="redirectTo" />
</bean>

<bean id="serverErrorHandler" class="com.apress.pss.terrormovies.security.ServerErrorFailureHandler"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: is this issue resolved? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use expressions with a custom AccessDecisionManager, you also need an expression voter, eg.

```
<bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter" />

            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: Tried with the same configuration but no luck.